# How to add header to the ngbtypeahead window?

Tags: ng-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to implement typeahead functionality in Angular. I am using ngbTypeahead from ng-bootstrap for this as shown below.

```
 <input id="typeahead-template" type="text" class="form-control form-rounded" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt" [inputFormatter]="formatter"  />

 <ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
 <img [src]="'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/'+r['flag']" class="mr-1" style="width: 16px">
 <ngb-highlight [result]="r.name" [term]="t"></ngb-highlight>
 </ng-template>
```

This is displaying result like

- result1
- result2
- result3

but I want a header to be added and the result should be in the format

- The results are
- result1
- result2
- result3

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported by ng-bootstrap's Typeahead component, however you can use CSS to insert text before the results. The only problem with this solution is that you need to use `::ng-deep` which is [deprecated and likely to be dropped by Angular soon](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160).

Add this to your component's CSS:

```
::ng-deep ngb-typeahead-window:before {
  content: "The results are:";
}
```

and you should see the following when results are displayed:

[image]

This will prepend the typeahead results with the text specified as the value of the `content` property.

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mf2nrr?file=app/typeahead-template.css) for a demo

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack I have been using:

1. Use the first row as a dummy row with a specific attribute
2. Track the existence of that attribute to render the header at the template
3. Use CSS to make the first row unselectable.

   .popup-custom-class .dropdown-item:first-of-type {
   pointer-events: none;
   }